Next js 14 app router always Hard refresh when behind cloudfront
I am working with nextJs 14 app router and it's behind CloudFront
My application works very weirdly it is always hard refresh  irrespective of whether I use the Link component of the nextJs.
I have noticed that when the application is not behind CloudFront for example on a local or development environment there is a different vary header.
Kindly help me find out how this issue can be solved.
I tried to write a policy on CloudFront to send the vary header which is expected
Update:
We have solved this by adding the cache policy at cloudfront to allow vary header with required values on request and response both

Were you able to resolve this issue?

@Programmeur yes we solved this issue by adding cache policy in CloudFront at by allowing the vary header at request and response

Thanks for the quick response! Just to be sure we're on the same page, did you edit your Cache Policy and add the Vary header in the "Cache key settings"?  That's as close as I found to "allow" a different header.

Update:
We have solved this by adding the cache policy at cloudfront to allow vary header with required values on request and response both
